# Do acids react with neutral salts?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base

I am new to the concept of neutralization.
My teacher told me that acids do not react with neutral salts.
I want to know *why* not.

If both are dissolved in water and both completely dissociate, why can't the ions of acid and salt exchange and perform a double displacement reaction.

Moreover I have seen the following reaction in a book: $$\ce{2 NaCl + H2SO4 -> 2 HCl + Na2SO4}$$

Comment: Indeed, they can and sometimes do react.

Comment: That last equation you have there isn't a *neutralization* reaction ;-)

Comment: This examples shows the danger of uncontrolled generalisations. Whether a reaction can 'happen' or not depends on its thermodynamics and kinetics, and that in turn depends on the species involved. You can't say _in general_ that 'neutral' salts don't react with acids. Take for instance $\ce{Ag2SO4 + 2 HCl <=> 2 AgCl + H2SO4}$. This reaction does happen and has a very high equilibrium constant, because $\ce{AgCl}$ is highly insoluble. Substitute $\ce{Ag}$ with $\ce{Na}$ and then it's the opposite of your example.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/5048/hcl-synthesis-from-sulfuric-acid-and-sodium-salt

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/76147/what-are-some-ways-to-predict-that-a-double-replacement-reaction-will-occur?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1):

Neutralization is a reaction between acid and base which results in the formation of a salt and water.
When you have any ionic compound and dissolve it into water, dissociation occurs.
This means that you get a solution of ions.
So if you dissolve acids, bases or salts into water, you end up with a mixture of ions.
Then, more things may happen or not.

In the case of the given reaction, you will get a solution with:

$\ce{Na+ + Cl- + H+ + SO4^{2-}}$

If the system is closed, nothing will happen.
But if the system is open, then $\ce{HCl}$ will evolve because it is a gas.
Since the sulphuric acid is very polar and a liquid, water is not even required.
This is, in fact, the standard procedure to prepare anhydrous HCL in the lab. Just drop $\ce{H2SO4}$ on $\ce{NaCl}$. It must be said that $\ce{NH4Cl}$ works better.